# Difference Between $n^{\Omega{(1)}}$ and $\Omega{(n)}$

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

I am not sure about the difference between $n^{\Omega(1)}$ and $\Omega(n)$. It seems to me that the only difference is that $n^{\Omega(1)}$ can contain some sublinear functions, i.e., $n^{\frac{1}{2}}$, which is not the case for $\Omega{(n)}$. Is there any other differences between these two notations?

Comment: You just explained what the difference is.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus So, $n^c \in \Omega(n), \forall 0<c<1$. And for the other, we have: $n^c \in n^{\Omega(1)}, \forall c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In fact, $n^c = \Omega(n)$ iff $c \geq 1$.